# Jquery fadeToggle on each element separately

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a tumblr theme, and I'm trying to achieve a Jquery effect in which when I click `.cari`, `.inpo` will fadeToggle. But, the problem is that there are more than 1 div with the class `.cari` and more than 1 div with the class `.inpo` and when one of the divs with the class `.cari` is clicked, all the divs with the class `.inpo` will fadeToggle. What should I do to make each `.inpo` fadeToggle only when its own `.cari` is clicked? I'm pretty sure there are similar questions asked here, but I am sorry though I cannot understand the solutions/answers. I am very new to Jquery/Javascript, so it'd be nice if the answer is to be simple and easy to understand. Sorry and thank you!

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2c6P.png

Hopefully, I made it easy to understand what I'd like to achieve.

Comment: A screenshot of code?? Don't you know copy-paste? =) What's your HTML structure etc.

Comment: Have to see the exact layout of your divs / what you've tried to be more helpful, but you will most likely be using the this keyword to access that one solely.

Comment: Sorry, it's my first time using stackoverflow.

I tried using the this keyword, but is it possible to change the css of another div when clicked on the this keyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your exact layout of your divs but here's an example

```
<div class="cari">?</div>
<div class="inpo">{block:Date}<a href="{Permalink}">{TimeAgo}{block:NoteCount} ({NoteCountWithLabel}){/block:NoteCount}</a>{/block:Date}</div>
<div class="cari">?</div>
<div class="inpo">{block:Date}<a href="{Permalink}">{TimeAgo}{block:NoteCount} ({NoteCountWithLabel}){/block:NoteCount}</a>{/block:Date}</div>
```

If your layout is like that

```
$(".cari").click(function () {
    $(this).next().fadeToggle();
});*
```

Basically [*this*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is the exact element in question (.inpo) so it grabs the next element and toggles just that one.

[Jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/aoo2uLtL/3/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But, my layout's unspecified- I think that's the correct term? The code is something like:

<div class="cari">?</div>
<div class="inpo">{block:Date}<a href="{Permalink}">{TimeAgo}{block:NoteCount} ({NoteCountWithLabel}){/block:NoteCount}</a>{/block:Date}</div>

So, all the permalinks will be classed in "inpo" and what I'm trying to do is to click on "cari" so that the "inpo" will fadeToggle.

Comment: if that's how your layout is http://jsfiddle.net/aoo2uLtL/3/ check out this example.

Comment: I think that might just work with a bit of a tweak on the placements of my divs since it's using next(), thank you so much!